# An Overview of Priming in Psychology

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, behavioral-economics, priming

I am looking for a comprehensive overview of priming literature in psychology and cognitive science. A survey article or a book would be a great start. More specifically, I am interested to learn about different types of priming, stimuli, and applications in which priming is used, in addition to some common methodological practices in this field. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update for those who think this question is not specific enough:** Which book do you recommend to a person interested in learning about priming in depth?

Comment: Is there a particular field of priming that you are interested in? I'm not an expert in the area, but for example, semantic priming and social priming tend to be quite distinct literatures.

Comment: At this time, I am interested to know the big picture of priming and the main distinctions between various types of priming. For example, what are the key differences between semantic priming and social priming?

Answer (score 2):

This should be rather easy to find on google scholar, especially with the recent replicability crisis in social psychology. In particular, Bargh and Cesario has a few things to say in 'defense' of priming.

You can start with [Bargh](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-natural-unconscious/201205/priming-effects-replicate-just-fine-thanks)'s article, which is a response to [this article by Bower](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/hot-and-cold-priming).

Cesario's article is [here](http://pps.sagepub.com/content/9/1/40.short), and for an overview of the whole issue surrounding priming and replicability, you can try [Pashler and Wagenmaker](http://pps.sagepub.com/content/7/6/528.short)'s article.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response and the pointers. I have spent some time on Google scholar but failed to find a book or a survey which gives me bird's-eye view of priming. Do you aware of any such references?

Comment: @abari I'm not formally trained in this area, but I'd imagine if you're just looking for a 'primer for priming' (heheh), then the wiki page for priming will give you this, no? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_(psychology). The rest just needs due diligence in reading the sources on that page.

Comment: I am already aware of the Wikipedia page. But, Wikipedia pages are not necessarily good scientific references. Also, their references do not always provide good starting points for a field.